# Kivy, glsl: why do I see a different display of the same shader?

Tags: python, glsl, kivy, shader

Here is an example that demonstrates the essence of my question.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.graphics import RenderContext
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import kivy.core.window

shader = '''
$HEADER$

uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void)
{
    vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy);

    float color = 0.0;
    color += position.y / position.x;
    if(color < 0.2) { color = 0.2; }
    vec3 output_color = vec3(color * 1.5, color, color * 2.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(output_color, 1.0);
}

'''

class ShaderWidget(Widget):
    fs = StringProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = RenderContext(use_parent_projection=True)
        super(ShaderWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.canvas['time'] = Clock.get_boottime()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_glsl, 1 / 60.)

    def update_glsl(self, *largs):
        self.canvas['time'] = Clock.get_boottime()
        self.canvas['resolution'] = [float(v) for v in self.size]

    def on_fs(self, instance, value):
        shader = self.canvas.shader
        shader.fs = value

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        main_widget = Factory.MainWidget()
        main_widget.mini.fs = shader
        main_widget.mini2.fs = shader
        return main_widget

TestApp().run()
```

test.kv:

```
<MiniShaderWidget@ShaderWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<MainWidget@ShaderWidget+FloatLayout>:
    mini: mini
    mini2: mini2

    BoxLayout
        MiniShaderWidget
            id: mini

        Label
            text: 'label'

        MiniShaderWidget
            id: mini2
```

In this application, I have a window that consists of three equal parts.

The shader from the same source (the variable *shader*) is drawn to the left and right.

The shader looks like a transition from white to violet.

In the middle, I added a label called "label" just to make it easier to distinguish the left shader from the right one.

I took this example and reworked it a bit from examples/shader/rotated.py (kivy github)

The question is:
I expect to see the same picture on the left and right, but I see different images of the same shader.
Why is this so?

Is it possible to make the same picture on the left and right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the delay:

Look at your .kv file and see how you setup your MiniShaderWidgets?

```
<MiniShaderWidget@ShaderWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Simply change your:

```
 pos: self.pos
 size: self.size
```

That is where it is getting the positioning and size information - simply change from self.size & self.pos to whatever you like.  You can use absolute numbers like (100, 100) or you could use size and positioning hints, or you could use math like

```
size: (self.width / 3, self.height)
```

Basically, all you need to do is review kivy sizing and positioning for *any* other widget and play with it to get what you want.

The shader code with the position logic: gl_FragCoord.xy is a distraction.

The shader code as written uses the *widgets* size and position - which is absolutely correct.

What you want to do is not have your widgets inherit their size and position from the main widget.

Think of it this way: you have two purple shader widgets drawing the same texture shading logic in the same places, and then you have a label box down the center.

You need to position the purple shader widgets where you want and the shader position logic will work just fine.

Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: So now that you see them as separate widgets, when you go to edit their size and position - you should create a separate shader widget to handle its different properties:

Create two different:

<MiniShaderWidget@ShaderWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
        Rectangle:
            pos: (300, 300)
            size: (100, 100)


<MiniShaderWidget2@ShaderWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
        Rectangle:
            pos: (50, 50)
            size: (200, 200)

Comment: Otherwise if you use one widget, and change its size and position, you will still end up rendering two identical widgets in the same place (but with your new size and position values)

Answer (score 1):

Fun question!

You actually do have two different "pictures" on the left and right, it looks like the same shader spread across the window with the label widget "floating on top" in the center. But this is an illusion.

You do have three different widgets, each different. But the illusion is caused because your shader function is taking the x, y position of screen-space to determine the color.

To illustrate this more clearly, I added a second shader and just tweaked the color scheme:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.graphics import RenderContext
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import kivy.core.window

shader = '''
$HEADER$

uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void)
{
    vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy);

    float color = 0.0;
    color += position.y / position.x;
    if(color < 0.2) { color = 0.2; }
    vec3 output_color = vec3(color * 1.5, color, color * 2.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(output_color, 1.0);
}

'''

shader2 = '''
$HEADER$

uniform vec2 resolution;

void main(void)
{
    vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy);

    float color = 0.0;
    color += position.y / position.x;
    if(color < 0.2) { color = 0.2; }
    vec3 output_color = vec3(color * 1.5, color * 2.0, color);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(output_color, 1.0);
}

'''

class ShaderWidget(Widget):
    fs = StringProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = RenderContext(use_parent_projection=True)
        super(ShaderWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.canvas['time'] = Clock.get_boottime()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_glsl, 1 / 60.)

    def update_glsl(self, *largs):
        self.canvas['time'] = Clock.get_boottime()
        self.canvas['resolution'] = [float(v) for v in self.size]

    def on_fs(self, instance, value):
        shader = self.canvas.shader
        shader.fs = value
        shader2 = self.canvas.shader
        shader2.fs = value

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        main_widget = Factory.MainWidget()
        main_widget.mini.fs = shader
        main_widget.mini2.fs = shader2
        return main_widget

TestApp().run()
```

I think your next question, will be, how do I pass in the position coordinates to the shader of the widget, and not the screen-space?

Comment: if I understand correctly, the left and right widgets differ, because shader coordinates depend not only on the size of a widget, but also on widget position on the app screen.
And yes, my main question is:
how do I pass in the position coordinates...
Because I want each shader to work only within its widget, regardless of the position of the widget:
if sizes of two widgets are the same and widgets have the same shader source, then I need these 2 widgets to look the same.
There is an example named shadertree in the official kivy repository on github.
Is this something that can come up?